# Show each person data on separate Report page using ReportViewer in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datasource, reportviewer

I am working on reports and i have to print each person data on a separate page I have writen a code in vb.net(WebApp) that gets each person data from database and sets DataSet but when i set ReportDataSource with that DataSet it shows only last record replacing all the previous rather than adding new page to show 2nd record and so on.. Can anyone please guide me to have each record on separate page in report.

Public Sub CustomReportShow(ByVal dset As DataSet)

```
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dset.Tables(0)))
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("DataSet2", dset.Tables(1)))
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("DataSet3", dset.Tables(2)))
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("DataSet4", dset.Tables(3)))
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("DataSet5", dset.Tables(4)))
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("DataSet6", dset.Tables(5)))
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("DataSet7", dset.Tables(6)))
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report.rdlc"
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh()
End Sub
```

Thanks

hamidnasir

Comment: Each person has different DataTable in the DataSet ?

Comment: Data Table 0 contains Person information, Data Table 1 contains education information  of a person and so on....
Mean all Tables data is combined to make complete information of a single person.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/8rxme5l.png
This is the report template to get person complete Information. it is working fine for single person info. but i want to show all person info on same report on each page of report.